# declare a variable in code behind

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

This is my Stored Procedure.

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(500)   
    select @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ';' ,'') + eml_ID from EmailGroup where eml_Level=3 and eml_Stat=1
SELECT @listStr
```

I dont have problem when I call this SP on my code behind.  What I want to do is to put this SP on my code behind.  This is what i tried in my code behind.

```
   using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string stR = @"select @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ';' ,'') + eml_ID from EmailGroup where eml_Level=3 and eml_Stat=1";

            using (SqlCommand cmD = new SqlCommand(stR, sqlConn))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dR = cmD.ExecuteReader();
                cmD.Parameters.Add("@listStr", SqlDbType.VarChar);


                while (dR.Read())
                {
                    string emailFullName = Session["UserFullName"].ToString(); 
                    string email = Session["UserEmailAdd"].ToString();
                     //more code here
                 }
```

When I tries this approach. I receive error "Must declare the scalar variable "@listStr".
My Question is how can i declare a variable in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omited in code behind the variable declaration.

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(500);
```

Your code should be:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string stR = @"DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(500); select @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ';' ,'') + eml_ID from EmailGroup where eml_Level=3 and eml_Stat=1";

        using (SqlCommand cmD = new SqlCommand(stR, sqlConn))
        {
          // Omitted
```

Beware to separate your statements with a semicolon ;

Comment: @odlanyer I have updated my answer, take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the value of listStr, try this:

```
cmD.Parameters.Add("@listStr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "test");
```

or

```
cmD.Parameters.Add("@listStr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "test";
```

And the compiler is looking for @listStr in your SELECT statement, which is not declared. You need to change your query with something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmD = new SqlCommand("StoredProcName", sqlConn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dR = cmD.ExecuteReader();
        cmD.Parameters.Add("@listStr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "test";


        while (dR.Read())
        {
            string emailFullName = Session["UserFullName"].ToString(); 
            string email = Session["UserEmailAdd"].ToString();
             //more code here
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: check my edit.replace your using statement with mine.

Comment: ok. let's use your stored proc, see my edit and replace storedProcName to your stored proc name. Let's see

Answer (score 0):

```
select @listStr = COALESCE(....
```

That should populate a variable, but will not return a result set that you can read with

```
while (dR.Read()) {}
```

You should remove the variable assignment if you are executing a query for results...

```
select COALESCE(....
```

Are you saying Stored Procedure when you mean Query? A Stored Procedure is a named "function" that expects parameters and returns data. A Stored Procedure contains one or more queries like what you wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a stored procedure, and I strongly recommend you to leverage on separating db implementation from DAL implementation.

So first create the stored procedure in the proper DB:

```
        USE myActualDb /* use the actual db name */
        GO

        CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmailList
            @eml_level int, /* use the actual datatype */
            @eml_stat int,  /* use the actual datatype */
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(500)   

            SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ';' ,'') + eml_ID
            FROM EmailGroup
            WHERE eml_Level = @eml_level AND eml_Stat = @eml_stat

            SELECT @listStr
        END
```

Then call the stored from the codebehind using ADO.NET SqlClient:

```
        var emlLevel = levelValue;
        var emlStat = statValue;

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "GetEmailList";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("eml_level", emlLevel));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("eml_level", emlStat));

                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    /* do whatever you need with the dr result */
                }


                /* clean up*/
            }
        }
```